# Before onCreateView starts

Tags: android, android-fragments

In PageFragment; I inflate a layout in onCreateView. But I want to inflate this layout before onCreateView loads. It could be inflated one time / or for every fragment; not important.

How can I achieve it ?

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {  
@Override  
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
     }  

     @Override  
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_quiz, container, false);  
          tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Text);  

         LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.questionList);

         return view;  
     }
}
```

Comment: Try doing that in `onCreate`.

Comment: I tried to inflate layout in onCreate as the same as onCreateView; but couldnt make it

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to pass `view` value to linearlayout from FragmentPagerAdapter somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to provide a layout as the return parameter in `onCreateView()`, that does not means you have to inflate it there. Layout can come from anywhere. You can Inflate the layout in `onAttach()` or in `onCreate()`.

use `getActivity()` to get a `LayoutInflater` instance:

```
View layout = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(........);
```